# Curie Weiss fit

Tags: ferromagnetism

I would like to know up to what point do we know our material is paramagnetic or not. I fitted a curie Weiss model in the linear region of my curves with different fields each and I am having positive and negative curie temperatures.

What does this means?

And finally. How do I really know I have reached the paramagnetic state?

Comment: How large are the error bars on those Curie temperatures? Are your extrapolated values consistent with 0 kelvin?

Comment: I got around -271+-1 K for one of the curves that it is indicative of an antiferromagnetic coupling and +181+-2K for the other two, indicative of ferromagnetic ordering.. I extrapolated them and got the same result as the fitting. I would like to know  if I can only achieve the paramagnetic state when the curie Weiss temperature is equal to zero.